# How to run this code in sequential way and get the result in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sequential

this result is always empty, because it is returned even before the async call is complete

```js
function(myList) {
    let result = []
    
    myList.forEach(async function(element)) {
        //api call
        result.push(status)
    }

    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `async` `await` with forEach loop. Use `map` with `Promise.all` or `for of` loop that is promise aware. For example:

```
const myList = ['abc', 'def'];

for (const foo of myList) {
    const result = await someResultfromApi;
    result.push(element);
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The array methods didn't accept async functions, so, in this particular case, you should use a basic loop

```
function (myList) {
  let result = [];
  for (let element: myList) {
    //api call with the await
    result.push(status);
  }
  return result;
}
```

or you can use reduce, if you want to use an array native function, it will look like this

```
function (myList) {
  return myList.reduce(
    (prev, element) => {
      return prev.then(result => {
        return http.get(/*some thing with the element*/).then(res => {
          result.push(res);
          return result;
        })
      });
    },
    Pormise.resolve([]));
}
```